# IE 9 rendering issue in standard mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

My application rendering well in IE9 Quirks Mode but not in standard mode.

For example: Rendering div background image in Quirks mode but not in standard mode.

[image: Image-1] Quirks Mode

[image: Image-2] Standard Mode

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: show us the code so we have a clue as to what to help you with

Comment: Rebuild your CSS according to w3c standards. Most problems on SO are a result of IE unintentionally rendering in quirks. You are the first question I have seen where the opposite is the case.

Comment: Code code code? Better yet if you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the CSS as follows.

```
display: inline;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
```

It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably use the **Strict** doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

validate the html by **w3c**:
`http://validator.w3.org/`